# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined of react.js

Tags: reactjs

Please why am I getting this TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined of react.js?

```
import React from 'react'
import './ListItems.css'

function ListItems(props) {
    const items = props.items;
    const ListItems = items.map (item =>
    {
        return <div className = "list" key = "item.key">
            <p>{item.text} </p>

        </div>
    })
    return (
    <div> {ListItems} </div>
    )
}

export default ListItems
```

Comment: @MajidMohammadi It's not null. OP didn't pass `items` as a prop that's why it says *Cannot read property 'map' of undefined*. `null` and `undefined` are two separate things in JS.

Comment: Defining something called `ListItems` *inside of* something called `ListItems` probably isn't the best idea either...

Comment: Aniket Agawal, Thanks, Is item suppose to be an array?

Comment: Are you passing `item` props to your child? Can you show your parent component?

Comment: It would be more helpful if you share `props.items` value too

Answer (score 0):

1. The items array is undefined which means that you either didn't pass the prop or you passed an undefined value or you made a typo
2. The key attribute is variable so you have to use `key={item.key}`

You can also make your code cleaner :

You can get rid of the `return` keyword by removing the curly braces :

```
items.map(item => (
   <div>
   </div>
))
```

I suggest you to destructure the props in the function parameter itself :

```
const ListItems = ({items}) => {
    // function code
}
```

Comment: 1. There can be a space. Try running on the console. 
Also, by removing the return, the error will not fix. It is cleaner code, but does not fix OPs problem.

Comment: I have written the third point which is the reason, I get your point, I'll shift it to the top

Comment: @TusharShahi ah yes my bad about the space, thought it was a bug

Answer (score 0):

no comment has been able to solve my problem. I am a total learner here. I will appreciate it if you break the explanations to an understandable level for me. Thanks

Comment: your 'props.items' is null so you should check it. const listItems = (props.items || [ ]).map( item => {});